# Warning paint queue size exceeded, please watch the amount of repaint calls Error

Tags: codenameone

I have about 50 plus rows in the table. If i display them in table as below, "Warning paint queue size exceeded, please watch the amount of repaint calls" 
error warning is shown infinitely. If i limit the row to 15 or 20 then it works normally.How can i solve the error.

Update: if i keep "showTableData(f)" in beforeMain, there is no warnings but if i comment it out and keep it in postMain, the warnings appear. Why is that?

```
 @Override
protected void beforeMain(Form f) {
 //        showTableData(f);
 //        f.revalidate();
}

Container wrapContainer;
Container containerTableDataGroup;
String detailId = "";

@Override
protected void postMain(Form f) {
    showTableData(f); //keeping table data here gives warnings
    f.forceRevalidate();
}

public void showTableData(Form f) {
    f.setScrollableY(true);
    wrapContainer = new Container();

    GroupConnection gc = new GroupConnection();
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {

        Container tableNameDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
        TextArea tableNameData = new TextArea();
        tableNameData.setText("tableNameData");
        stylingTextArea(tableNameData);
        tableNameData.setActAsLabel(true);
        tableNameDataContainer.add(tableNameData);

        Container inaugurationDateDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
        TextArea inaugurationDateData = new TextArea();
        inaugurationDateData.setText("inaugurationDate");
        stylingTextArea(inaugurationDateData);
        inaugurationDateData.setActAsLabel(true);
        inaugurationDateDataContainer.add(inaugurationDateData);

        Container areaCodeDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
        TextArea areaCodeData = new TextArea();
        areaCodeData.setText("areaCodeData");
        stylingTextArea(areaCodeData);
        areaCodeData.setActAsLabel(true);
        areaCodeDataContainer.add(areaCodeData);

        Container clubAbbrNameDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
        TextArea clubAbbrNameData = new TextArea();
        clubAbbrNameData.setText("clubAbbrNameData");
        stylingTextArea(clubAbbrNameData);
        clubAbbrNameData.setActAsLabel(true);
        clubAbbrNameDataContainer.add(clubAbbrNameData);

        Container clubCharterDateDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
        TextArea clubCharterDateData = new TextArea();
        clubCharterDateData.setText("clubCharterDateData");
        stylingTextArea(clubCharterDateData);
        clubCharterDateData.setActAsLabel(true);
        clubCharterDateDataContainer.add(clubCharterDateData);

        TableLayout tl1 = new TableLayout(1, 5);
        containerTableDataGroup = new Container(tl1);
        containerTableDataGroup.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(30), tableNameDataContainer);
        containerTableDataGroup.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(20), inaugurationDateDataContainer);
        containerTableDataGroup.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(15), areaCodeDataContainer);
        containerTableDataGroup.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(15), clubAbbrNameDataContainer);
        containerTableDataGroup.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(20), clubCharterDateDataContainer);

        wrapContainer.add(containerTableDataGroup);

    }
    f.add(wrapContainer);
    wrapContainer.revalidate();
}

public void stylingTextArea(TextArea textAreaName) {
    textAreaName.setUIID("styleTextArea");
    textAreaName.getAllStyles().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_SMALL));
    textAreaName.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    textAreaName.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
    textAreaName.setEditable(false);
    textAreaName.setGrowByContent(true);
    textAreaName.setGrowLimit(2);
}
```

Update 2: 
   If I keep connection in beforeForm method using addToQueue, the blank screen is displayed. If i use addToQueueAndWait, the infinite progress is shown only for a short period of time, only couple of seconds later the datas are displayed(smtimes take much more time to display). I had used actionlistener callback in connection request method in postForm and addToQueue works but same is not working in beforeForm.

```
protected void beforeGroups(Form f) {
   groupConnection();

   wrapContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        for (Map<String, Object> element : response) {
            String tableName = (String) element.get("name");
            . . . . . . . 
            . . . . . . . 
        }
}

void groupConnection() {
    ConnectionRequest connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser jSONParser = new JSONParser();
            Map<String, Object> parsedData = jSONParser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
            response = (ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) parsedData.get("root");
        }
    };
    connectionRequest.setUrl(allUrl.groupsUrl);
    InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
    Dialog d = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
    connectionRequest.setDisposeOnCompletion(d);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(connectionRequest);//blank screen if addToQueueAndWait isnot used here
}
```

Update 3:

```
@Override
protected void beforeAbc(Form f) {
    minuteConnection(f);
}   

void minuteConnection(Form f) {
    ConnectionRequest connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser jSONParser = new JSONParser();
            Map<String, Object> parsedData = jSONParser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
            responsee = (ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) parsedData.get("root");
        }

        @Override
        protected void postResponse() {
            int i = 0;
            wrapContainerMeeting = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            for (Map<String, Object> element : responsee) {
                String minuteId = (String) element.get("meetingNumberId");
                String tblId = (String) element.get("tbladmin_id");
                String tableName = (String) element.get("name");
                String totalMembers = (String) element.get("continousMeetingNumber");
                String totalMeetingYearly = (String) element.get("meetingForYear");
                String minuteDate = (String) element.get("meetingDate");

                Container tableNameDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
                TextArea tableNameDataMeeting = new TextArea(tableName);
                tableNameDataContainer.add(tableNameDataMeeting);

                Container inaugurationDateDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
                TextArea inaugurationDateDataMeeting = new TextArea(totalMembers);
                inaugurationDateDataContainer.add(inaugurationDateDataMeeting);

                Container areaCodeDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
                TextArea areaCodeData = new TextArea(totalMeetingYearly);
                areaCodeDataContainer.add(areaCodeData);

                Container clubAbbrNameDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
                TextArea clubAbbrNameData = new TextArea(minuteDate);
                clubAbbrNameDataContainer.add(clubAbbrNameData);
            }
            f.add(wrapContainerMeeting);
        }
    };
    AllUrl allUrl = new AllUrl();
    connectionRequest.setUrl(allUrl.abcUrl);
    connectionRequest.setPost(false);//keeping this line or deleting doesnt affect anything
    InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
    Dialog d = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
    connectionRequest.setDisposeOnCompletion(d);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(connectionRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `revalidate` for every single row you add which is very excessive...

You need to do this once after you finish adding everything.

Comment: In postGroup, f.revalidate is used at last line , so i think everything is finished adding at that time. If I comment it out, the warning is not shown but the table doesnt appear unless i touch in the screen. But if i add that line, the table with many more warning appears.

Comment: Try removing all the revalidate calls and only call forceRevalidate in the postGroup.

Comment: Do you only invoke it once? Notice that you should remove all the other revalidate calls

Comment: The error warning reappeared again. I think i found the reason. If i use label and spanlabel instead of TextArea, the warning isnt there. I have used revalidate() only once at the end. Is there bug in textArea? I need the growLimit to 2. I have no any gradients and other fancy styling. Moreover i use simple theme with a search textfield and then a table layout for table. If i see in performance monitor, other container etc have invocations value 1 but textarea has 51. What is the reason behind it? Also i dont find much difference in fastest and slowest value betn textarea and other components

Comment: When you create the text area give it more columns (e.g. 20) otherwise it reflows to grow and could trigger a performance penalty because of excessive repaints.

Comment: setColumns(20) or more doesnt solve the problem. The warning doesnt go. I have seen others complaining warning msg about the textArea as well but no real soln there too. The warning is shown infinitely if i have more than 23 textArea in a loop. Less than that there is no warning msg. This warning has no much effect in simulator but in devices it makes the app slower.

Comment: When you construct the text area do you give it the text? You can also use setActAsLabel(true) and see if that works. Since SpanLabel is inherently a text area and you say it works then these are the only two differences...

Comment: setActAsLabel(true) gives warnings too. I have tested it more than 2 weeks now. But today i found out that if i keep all my textAreas in beforeMain, there is no warnings. But as soon as i keep them in postMain, there is problem. What is the reason behind it? I have created a test case above in the question. Plz hav a look.

Comment: That makes sense and you should usually do as much as possible in the before and rarely use post. Every call you add after the form is shown requires far more work to adapt to a form that's already potentially visible. So you are slowing down your application significantly thru excessive work. All our samples/tutorials always talk about using the before* methods and never the post.

Comment: I usually use post if i have connectionRequest. If i use before, then it takes a bit time to go to next form and user may click multiple times in the button . It causes problems. Is there any way to fix it? And one more thing, If i use barebone code, Is there any before and post logic there too?

Comment: You shouldn't use the `AndWait` version of the methods for this case.

Comment: If i dont use AndWait version, the blank form is displayed. I used addToQueue successfully only in postForm using actionListener callback but same doesnt work in beforeForm. I have updated above the problem in beforeForm (plz hav a look at update 2)

Comment: Use the addToQueue without wait. Call showTableData from the `postResponse` callback of the `ConnectionRequest`.

Comment: If i use addToQueue only and call the data from postResponse, the form returns back to same form and infinite progress doesnt show up. Plz see update 3: above if i have done all right or not. thankyou

Comment: That's because you show the infinite progress when the old form is still showing so the disposal goes back to that form. Try to do the andWait call in the before* call.